# Check whether checkbox is selected or not in gridview then display tooltip

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am using Grid view and a link button in asp.net c# application like below lines of code.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSaveTop" title="Send Mail" Style="float: right" CssClass="btn btn-u"  data-rel="tooltip"  ToolTip="Send Email"
                data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top"
                data-content="Select Mail then Click to Send..." OnClick="BtnSend_Click"
                OnClientClick="alert()" runat="server">Send Mail</asp:LinkButton>

    <asp:GridView ID="grdNotificationSystem" CssClass="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" DataKeyNames="NotificationSystemID"
            OnRowDataBound="grdNotificationSystem_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="grdNotificationList_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                    <ItemTemplate> 
                            <label class="checkbox" >
                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkRow" /><i></i> &nbsp;</label>

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgBtncommand" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Visible="false"
                            CommandArgument='<%# Bind("NotificationSystemID") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
              ...
              ...
              </columns>
          <asp:GridView/>
```

Now I want that if any checkbox is selected then mail should be send otherwise send button "lnkSaveTop" should be disabled or unclickable and then tooltip with the message "Select Mail then Click to Send..." should be popped out on this button . Please help me!!!

Comment: You want to do that on client side? Have you any javascript code?

Comment: Yes I want to do this on the client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```
$(function() {
     if (!($('#<%= grdNotificationSystem.ClientID %> tr td').find('input:checkbox').is(':checked'))) {
         $('#<%= lnkSaveTop.ClientID%>').attr('disabled', true).attr('title', 'Select Mail then Click to Send...');
     }
 });

 $('#<%= grdNotificationSystem.ClientID %> tr td').find('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $('#<%= lnkSaveTop.ClientID%>').prop('disabled', false).attr('title', '');
     } else {
         $('#<%= lnkSaveTop.ClientID%>').prop('disabled', true).attr('title', 'Select Mail then Click to Send...');
     }

 });
```

Comment: Can you do me a favour just add an alert before `$('#<%= lnkSaveTop.ClientID%>')` this line and run again. If  an alert pops up then change from **prop** to **attr**.

Comment: If I use alert before $('#<%= lnkSaveTop.ClientID%>') line, the alert is poped up when the page is loaded fiirst time

Comment: Perfect, Now as told earlier just replace **.prop** with **.attr** and i am now updating rest of code to enable link button when the checkbox is selected.

Comment: but the link button is not disabled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89789/discussion-between-suprabhat-and-user2179026).

Comment: There was a minor issue with the code i have now resolved it please apply the same.